# How to rewrite code in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've got some piece of working code and need more clear implementation  using lodash library. 
Need some advice how to rewrite the code.
I need just advice, not `rewrite it instead me`

```
function extractHeaders(headers/*string of http headers*/) {

    return headers
        .trim()
        .split('\n')
        .map(function (x) {
            var index = x.indexOf(':');
            var key = x.slice(0, index).trim();
            var value = x.slice(index + 1).trim();
            var y = {};

            y[key] = value;

            return y;
        })
        .reduce(function (acc, item) {
            return _.assign(acc, item);
        }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want just a hint, then `_.zipObject` and `String.split` are your friends ;)

Side advice: Don't implement your own HTTP-parsing library. [This is much more complicated than you would expect, as shown in Chapter 3 of "The Tangled Web"](https://www.nostarch.com/download/tangledweb_ch3.pdf).